# Riemann sum equations

Tags: c, sum

I have an equation for finding the mid point value for the Riemann sum, but it is not providing the correct value for the midpoint when entering coefficients `3, 4, 0` and upper and lower limits of `-1` and `1` with 10 rectangles.

```
float getMidPoint(int final, int initial, int rectangle, int coefficient1, int coefficient2, int coefficient3)
{
    float deltaX;
    float sumMidPoint;
    float f_X;
    float x;
    x = initial;
    deltaX = (final - initial) / rectangle;
    while(x < final)
    {
        f_X = pow((coefficient1 * x), 2) + (coefficient2 * x) + coefficient3;

        sumMidPoint += f_X * deltaX;
        x = x + deltaX;
    }
    return (sumMidPoint);
}
```

I am not sure why I am not getting the correct value for sumMidPoint. The test case has the sumMidPoint = 1.980000 sq. units

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I am not sure why I am not getting the correct value for sumMidPoint. The test case has the sumMidPoint = 1.980000 sq. units

Comment: Use a debugger and step through the code.

Comment: " I am not getting the correct value for sumMidPoint" --> what was the incorrect value your received?

Comment: The Riemann tag refers to the systems monitoring library of the same name, rather than the math function. It's rather unfortunate that so many things in the software world use the same name. So I hope you don't mind my removing the tag.

Answer (score -1):

Two issues:

1. final, initial and rectangle are all integers, therefore you're making an integer division:

(final - initial) / rectangle = 2/20 = 0.1 in float but 0 in int

to correct, set at least one of them as float, but better both:

```
float final, float initial
```

2. Your second error is in the formula: 3x^2 is 3 * pow(x, 2). You wrote (3x)^2.
3. Also, to be safe, don't forget to initialize your sumMidPoint variable before using it:

   float sumMidPoint = 0;

Here is my final version of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float getMidPoint(float final, int initial, int rectangle, int   coefficient1, int coefficient2, int coefficient3) {
    float deltaX = (final - initial) / rectangle;
    float sumMidPoint = 0;
    float f_X;
    float x = initial + deltaX / 2;

    for(int i=0; i< rectangle; i++)
    {
        f_X = (coefficient1 * pow( x, 2)) + (coefficient2 * x) + coefficient3;

        sumMidPoint += f_X * deltaX;
        x = x + deltaX;
    }
    return(sumMidPoint);

}

int main() {
    printf("Result: %f\n", getMidPoint(1, -1, 10, 3, 4, 0));
    return(0);
}
```

Output:
**Result: 1.980000**

Comment: I tried this, and I'm still not getting the correct value. I have added x = x + (deltaX / 2) and that also isn't helping

Comment: In the test trial the answer is 1.980000 so the quadratic function would read 3x^2 + 4x + 0 with a = -1 and b = 1 with n = 10 for the proper Riemann sum notation.

Comment: `(coefficient1*x + coefficient2)*x + coefficient3;` is numerically more stable and likely faster than `(coefficient1 * pow( x, 2)) + (coefficient2 * x) + coefficient3` is n

Comment: Suggest not changing function signature from `int`s and instead `float deltaX = (1.0f*final - initial) / rectangle;`